# jQuery: datepicker, alert the dayname of the selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

How can i alert the selected days name? Example 'Monday'.

So when you pick 7th june 2011 it will alert "Tuesday"

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#date" ).datepicker({ 
     dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
     onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
    // how can i grab the day name of the day, example "Monday" and alert it out?
    // alert( ? );
     }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The jQueryUI's Datepicker comes with a [`formatDate`](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/formatDate) function that can do that for you. If you're using a localized version, it'll show the days in that language too.

```
onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
  var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
  alert($.datepicker.formatDate('DD', date));
}
```

For more information on localization of on Dapicker's utility functions, have a look at http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/.

Comment: Note: the `date` **has to be** a JavaScript **`Date` object**, which IS provided by datepicker's `getDate()`. Altough, it might not be that clear if you are formatting date that *does not come from* datepicker. If you pass just string - you will get funny errors like `b.getMonth is not a function` etc...

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#date" ).datepicker({ 
         dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
         onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
         var weekday=new Array(7);
         weekday[0]="Sunday";
         weekday[1]="Monday";
         weekday[2]="Tuesday";
         weekday[3]="Wednesday";
         weekday[4]="Thursday";
         weekday[5]="Friday";
         weekday[6]="Saturday";

         alert(weekday[inst.getDate().getDay()];
     }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: inst.getDate() is not a function

Answer (score 1):

this will work if you don't mind showing the name of the day in the input box
if you dont like it you can use second hidden input (http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#alt-field)

```
$(function() {
    $( "#date" ).datepicker({
     dateFormat: 'DD, d MM, yy',
     onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
         var stop = dateText.indexOf(',');
        alert( dateText.substring(0, stop));
     }
    });
});
```

example at http://jsfiddle.net/aa74R/

Answer (score 0):

You can parse a date like this (`mm/dd/yyyy`):

```
new Date(Date.parse("06/07/2011"))
```

and use the `.getDay` function. You could do this:

```
// parse data
var regexp = /(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{2})/.exec("07/06/11");

//form date
var date = new Date(Date.parse(regexp[2] + "/" + regexp[1] + "/20" + regexp[3]));

alert(date.getDay()); // 2 -> Tuesday (starts at 0 = Sunday)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use inbuilt function

```
$("#datepicker" ).datepicker({  onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {

alert($.datepicker._defaults.dayNames[new Date(dateText).getDay()]);

}});
```